# In laravel 5, how to access to Command class methods from outside classes?

Tags: php, debugging, command-line, console, laravel-5

I'm developing a Illuminate\Console\Command. 
To be run via cli using php artisan.
This Command class is using other classes.
I appreciate the Command->info(), Command->error(), methods...
How can I use them in dependencies?

Until now I'm passing to other classes $this as parameter

e.g.

```
class MyClass extends Command {
....
    $g = new MyOtherClass($this, $param...);
    $g->find();
....
}

class MyOtherClass {
$command;
....
    public function __construct($command){
        $this->command=$command;
    }
    public function find(){
        if($error)
             $this->command->error($error);
    }
....
}
```

I wished methods could be accessed statically 
like:
     Command::error("some error");

But maybe this is not the intended use?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use "**echo**" to return instead "**$this->command->error**", because you can use in Kernel and save in a different log, like this:

```
echo '['.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'] local.ERROR: '.$error.PHP_EOL; // This way it will be better visible in log viewer.
```

And in app\Console\Kernel.php

```
$schedule->command('mycommand')
            ->everyTenMinutes()
            ->sendOutputTo(storage_path('logs/mycommand.log'))
            ->name('mycommand')
            ->withoutOverlapping();
```

Comment: when run a command how to breakdown echo? I used '<br/>','\n' but it's not working.